# Quiero que al escribir una opción en un campo de texto se marque el checkbox que le corresponde

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo unos elementos checkbox, que según los maroo o desmarco, se me añaden o eliminan de un campo text-area. En el código que dejo, podéis verlo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <form name="f1" id="miFormulario">
    <h2 align="center">Lista de números.</h2>
    <table style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero1" class="NUMEROS" value="Uno">Uno</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero2" class="NUMEROS" value="Dos">Dos</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero3" class="NUMEROS" value="Tres">Tres</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero5" class="NUMEROS" value="Cuatro">Cuatro</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero6" class="NUMEROS" value="Cinco">Cinco</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero7" class="NUMEROS" value="Seis">Seis</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero4" class="NUMEROS" value="Siete">Siete</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero8" class="NUMEROS" value="Ocho">Ocho</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero7" class="NUMEROS" value="Nueve">Nueve</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <section>
      <textarea id="text-area-numeros" name="textarea" style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea>
    </section>
  </form>

  <br>

  <script>
    var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".NUMEROS");
    var textArea = document.getElementById("text-area-numeros");
    var listArray = [];

    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
      checkbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (this.checked === true) {
          listArray.push(this.value);
          textArea.value = listArray.join(';');
        } else {
          listArray = listArray.filter((e) => e !== this.value);
          textArea.value = listArray.join(';');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Si manualmente escribo en el text-area uno de esos valores, quisiera que se marcara el checkbox que corresponde con el que acabo de escribir, y si lo elimino del text-area, que se desmarque el checkbox que le corresponde.

Comment: Si por ejemplo, se escribe "Nueve", y luego se borra un caracter (quedando algo así como "Nuev"), ¿debería desmarcarse el checkbox relacionado? ¿y si se escribe "Nueve" más de una vez?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828694/6300134

Comment: Si se quita un carácter, si se debería desmarcar, y en el caso que se escriba varias veces pues no hará nada y si quita un nueve y queda otro nueve pues no debería desmarcarlo, porque no se si se podrá controlar que no lo meta más de una vez, pero eso será ya mas complejo.

Answer (score 0):

En palabras, cada vez que cambia el contenido del textArea, sería de:

- inicializar los checkboxes
- convertir el texto en una lista de elementos
- iterar por dicha lista y, para cada elemento,

  - iterar por los checkboxes para ver si el texto coincide con el del checkbox
  - si coincide, marcar el checkbox.

Al final, quedas con los elementos que están en la lista, marcados en los checkboxes.

Manteniendo tu diseño actual, en código sería algo como:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".NUMEROS");
var textArea = document.getElementById("text-area-numeros");
var listArray = [];

checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.checked === true) {
      listArray.push(this.value);
      textArea.value = listArray.join(';');
    } else {
      listArray = listArray.filter((e) => e !== this.value);
      textArea.value = listArray.join(';');
    }
  });
});

textArea.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  listArray = [];
  checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => checkbox.checked = false);
  var txt = textArea.value;
  var lines = txt.split(";");
  lines.forEach((line) => {
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
      if (checkbox.value == line) {
        checkbox.checked = true;
        listArray.push(line);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="f1" id="miFormulario">
    <h2 align="center">Lista de números.</h2>
    <table style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero1" class="NUMEROS" value="Uno">Uno</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero2" class="NUMEROS" value="Dos">Dos</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero3" class="NUMEROS" value="Tres">Tres</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero5" class="NUMEROS" value="Cuatro">Cuatro</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero6" class="NUMEROS" value="Cinco">Cinco</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero7" class="NUMEROS" value="Seis">Seis</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero4" class="NUMEROS" value="Siete">Siete</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero8" class="NUMEROS" value="Ocho">Ocho</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="numero7" class="NUMEROS" value="Nueve">Nueve</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <section>
      <textarea id="text-area-numeros" name="textarea" style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea>
    </section>
  </form>

  <br>
```

El código del ejemplo no está listo para producción, debes considerar casos como que se corte o pegue texto con el ratón, etc., pero ya tienes una base de la cual partir.